# How to backend encrypt/decrypt in laravel or php?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Front End use:  cryptojs

```js
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("9999999999999999");
console.log(key)
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("9999999999999999");
console.log(iv)
var text = 'testing';
var encrypted = '' + CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text), key, { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
console.log(encrypted)
```

How to backend encrypt/decrypt using laravel or php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's encrypt/decrypt helpers if data is encrypted using the key that is stored in **key** option in your **config/app.php**.

```
$decrypted = decrypt($encryptedValue);
```

See Laravel docs for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/encryption

You can also use **OpenSSL** extension's functions to encrypt/decrypt **AES**, especially if you used a different key to encrypt the value:

```
$decryptedString = openssl_decrypt($encryptedString, 'AES-256-CBC', $key);
```

See the docs for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: Padding is missing.

```
\openssl_encrypt(
        'encrypted value',
        'algorithm', 'key', 'payload pad', 'iv'
    )

$value = \openssl_encrypt(
        'udaiyar',
        'aes-128-cbc', '5555555555555555', **128/8**, '5555555555555555'
    );
```